# Installing qlfw3 without root access

Tags: cmake, glfw

I'm working on a project that requires the glfw3 package. I have tried installing glfw3 which requires access to "/usr/local/include". But since I don't have root access, permission to make directory GLFW is denied. How can I get around this?

Comment: @BrettHale, Since glfw uses a CMake-based build system and the question is about building and installing it the package, tagging the question with [cmake] is sensible and appropriate.  But the question has nothing to do with the Autotools or pkg-config, and therefore it should not be so tagged .  That you choose to refer to those in your (very nice; +1) answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - you're right, of course. I guess I was trying to provide a cross reference via tags to something that exceeded the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. That's a *cmake* default. If you want a nice interactive configuration, go to the top level of the source tree and type `ccmake .` There you'll easily find the option to override the `INSTALL_PREFIX`. If you hit `'t'`, you get more advanced options. When done, `'g'` will generate the Makefiles and exit. I install a lot of my local libraries for my projects in `$HOME/local`. `glfw` is one of them. As well as prepending `$HOME/local/bin` to `PATH` and `$HOME/local/lib` to `[DY]LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It's served me well, having something of a local sandbox to develop in.

Even better, it installs `lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc`, which makes my life easier, building apps with GLFW, querying dependencies, include paths, library paths, libraries / frameworks by using `pkg-config` (with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Users/brett/local/lib/pkgconfig` set in my shell script for all my other `.pc` metadata files.

It also allows me to integrate GLFW3 easily into autotools. `pkg-config` provides initialization macros like:

```
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG([0.29]) # defines PKG_CONFIG variable.
```

And allows me to write some user-friendly scripts to integrate GLFW3 into my package, e.g.,

```
AC_MSG_RESULT([])
AC_MSG_RESULT([GLFW3 for OpenGL window and event management...])

PKG_CHECK_MODULES_STATIC([GLFW3], [glfw3 >= 3.2.1],
  [ac_glfw3_version=`$PKG_CONFIG glfw3 --modversion`],
  [ac_glfw3_version=;])

if test "x$ac_glfw3_version" != x ; then

  GLFW_VIS_CXXFLAGS=`echo $GLFW3_CFLAGS`
  GLFW_VIS_LIBFLAGS=`echo $GLFW3_LIBS`

  AC_MSG_RESULT([GLFW3 version: $ac_glfw3_version])
  AC_MSG_RESULT([CXXFLAGS: $GLFW_VIS_CXXFLAGS])
  AC_MSG_RESULT([LIBFLAGS: $GLFW_VIS_LIBFLAGS])

else

  dnl ... something else? ...

  AC_MSG_WARN([the vis library will be omitted from the build:])
  AC_MSG_RESULT([GLFW3 @ glfw.org])

  dnl ... or just AC_MSG_FAILURE? ...
fi
```

I've resisted `cmake` for now. As it grows in complexity due to the realities of real software development, I feel it reinvents the `autotools` wheel. Without the 20+ years of platform quirks and experience to draw on. Except that with `cmake` you need a whole host of extra support software just to build that wheel...